# How to pass both true/false and model in Request.CreateResponse in web Api without altering model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(string email, string password)
    {
        bool Isremember = false;
        LogedinUser user = UserHelper.Login(email, password, Isremember);
        if (user.Email == string.Empty)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, user);
        }
        else
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
    }
```

Now  response am getting,

if user not exists it is like

```
{"Id":0,"Email":"","Password":"","UserType":0,"OrganizationNumber":"","CompanyName":"","Name":"","Status":0}
```

an if exist

```
{"Id":0,"Email":"admin@gmail.com","Password":"123456","UserType":2,"OrganizationNumber":"133","CompanyName":"testcomp","Name":"","Status":1}
```

how to append one more parameter to response ie, `result:false/true`

Comment: is there any way without altering the model

Answer (score 0):

You can change your User model or create new viewmodel and adding some property in it and sending to client.

Comment: is there any way without altering the model

Comment: Yes,Create new model and inherit it from User and add in it.